# Timeout settings seem to have no effect

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, servicestack

I am trying to set a timeout for a special request which will take a long time to process. Because of this, I am trying to set the timeout, like this:

```
client.RequestFilter = r => {
    r.Timeout = 1000000;
    r.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000;
}
```

However, these settings seem to have no effect; the request still times out in about 30 seconds. Is there some hack I can use to set the timeout properly ?

ETA: The response I'm receiving is a stream; I do it like this:

```
var stream = client.Send<Stream>(requestDto);
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Please always include the StackTrace / Exception message (and .NET platform Info, i.e. .NET version or if Mono / iOS / Android, etc) where possible.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack's Service Clients is just a wrapper around HttpWebRequest so your code ends up setting the `HttpWebRequest` [Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ReadWriteTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) properties directly.

The Request Filter gives you direct access to the `HttpWebRequest` instance used and setting the Timeout properties should work as expected. Other than that the only class that can modify behavior of .NET's HttpWebRequest is `System.Net.ServicePointManager` which lets you configure some properties like `DefaultConnectionLimit` and `DnsRefreshTimeout`, etc. But there's no additional Request Timeout properties.

The alternative solution you can try is to use ServiceStack's [JsonHttpClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#jsonhttpclient) which as it's built on Microsoft's newer `HttpClient` library, you may have better luck with it. Although it's recommended to use the Async API's since the Sync API's are just blocking on the HttpClient's underlying Async API's.

For the API call itself, you should access the stream in a using block, e.g:

```
using (var stream = client.Send<Stream>(requestDto))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks mythz, I will try this once I get back to the office, but meanwhile, can you explain the comment about async APIs ? In my case, I actually want the call to block; more specifically, I am going to read the response stream on a background thread, parse it, perform some calculations, and periodically report progress to the UI (which is a Windows Forms application). Is there a better way ?

Comment: @Bugmaster I'm saying that Microsoft's new `HttpClient` only offers Async API's, to implement the Sync API's we're just blocking on the Task to get the result. This can work but it's not optimal. With Async API's in most cases you don't need the background thread since their non-blocking, so I'd just await on the Main UI thread and do all processing there. The [HelloMobile](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) project has some examples of calling Async API's in GUI Apps.